# Regex_match doesn't match in a file

Tags: regex, c++11

I want to recognize some lines in a text file using regex, but regex_match doesn't match any line, even if I use regex patron(".*")

```
string dirin = "/home/user/in.srt";
string dirout = "/home/user/out.srt";
ifstream in(dirin.c_str());
ofstream out(dirout.c_str());

string line;
// regex patron("(\\d{2}):(\\d{2}):(\\d{2}),(\\d{3})\\s-->\\s(\\d{2}):(\\d{2}):(\\d{2}),(\\d{3})");
regex patron(".*");
smatch m;
while (getline(in, line)) {
  if (regex_match(line, m, patron)) {
    out << "ok";
  };
  out << line;
}
in.close();
out.close();
```

The code always print the string line in the out.srt file, but never the string "ok" inside the if (regex_match(line, m, patron)).
I'm testing it with the following lines

1

00:01:00,708 --> 00:01:01,800

*You look at that river*

2

00:01:02,977 --> 00:01:04,706

*gently flowing by.*

3

00:01:06,213 --> 00:01:08,238

*You notice the leaves*

Comment: Are we supposed to guess what you are trying to match?

Comment: I want to match with the commented line, but doen't match any line

Comment: @DiegoSilvera - cannot reproduce: with your code, all line (empty too) generate an "ok"

Comment: You need to append `\n?` at the end of the pattern. `regex patron("(\\d{2}):(\\d{2}):(\\d{2}),(\\d{3})\\s-->\\s(\\d{2}):(\\d{2}):(\\d{2}),(\\d{3})\n?");` or `regex patron(".*\n?");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `getline()` reads a line with a trailing *carriage return* CR symbol, and note that ECMAScript `.` pattern does not match CR symbol considering it an end of line symbol.

`regex_match` requires that a whole string matches the pattern.

Thus, you need to account for an optional carriage return at the end of the pattern. You can do it by appending `\r?` or `\s*` at the end of the pattern:

```
regex patron("(\\d{2}):(\\d{2}):(\\d{2}),(\\d{3})\\s-->\\s(\\d{2}):(\\d{2}):(\\d{2}),(\\d{3})\\s*");
```

or

```
regex patron(".*\\s*");
```

Also, consider using raw string literals if your C++ version allows it:

```
regex patron(R"((\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2}),(\d{3})\s-->\s(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2}),(\d{3})\s*)");
```